# How to Get Matches From a Parser Derived Struct?

Tags: rust, clap

The documentation has got me confused. I'm kind of stuck on how to get matches from a parser derived struct. How would I go about doing this? Here's what my argument struct looks like.

```
#[derive(Parser)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
pub struct Args {
    /// Host address
    #[clap(short, long)]
    pub host: String,
    /// Database username
    #[clap(short, long)]
    pub username: String,
    /// Database password
    #[clap(short='P', long)]
    pub password: String,
    /// Database name
    #[clap(short='d', long)]
    pub database: String,
    /// Database port number
    #[clap(short, long, default_value_t = 3306)]
    pub port: u32,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`clap::Parser`](https://docs.rs/clap/3/clap/trait.Parser.html) trait has a method [`parse`](https://docs.rs/clap/3/clap/trait.Parser.html#method.parse) that you can use, that will read the arguments into a structure of the type, or exit the process on error.

```rust
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
pub struct Args {
    /// Host address
    #[clap(short, long)]
    pub host: String,
    ...
}

fn main() {
  let args = Args::parse();
  println!("got host: {}", args.host);
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for that. How about if I wanted to get an argument that has a list of values? How would I get the list of values using this parser method?

Comment: just use Vec as the type of option field: `#[clap(short, long)]
pub hosts: Vec<String>` and Clap will figure it out.